# I want Selenium python to refresh the page if a certain text is visible in an xpath and to not refresh if another text appears in the xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, text, find

Here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="comProductTile__soldOut add8top">Sold Out</div>
```

I am locating the text in the xpath using the following:

```
x = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="collectionApp"]/div/div/div[10]/a/div[4]/div[3]/div').text
```

It returns "Sold Out".  When that happens I want to refresh the page.  However, when the text in the xpath changes to "In Stock", I want the refreshing to stop.  How would I accomplish that?  Any help would be appreciated.   Thanks.

```
x = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="collectionApp"]/div/div/div[10]/a/div[4]/div[3]/div').text
if x = ("Sold Out")
        wd.refresh
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
```

I tried many iterations similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using `while` loop:

```
while True:
  x = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="collectionApp"]/div/div/div[10]/a/div[4]/div[3]/div').text
  if x == "Sold out":
    wd.refresh()
    time.sleep(2)
  elif x == "In Stock":
    break
```